# How to obtain results in months from relative survival quantiles?

Tags: survival, quantiles

I am doing relative survival analyses of a metastatic colorectal cancer population. Instead of looking at the usual 1- or 5-year relative survival percentages, I am calculating 5 different survival percentiles (p10, p25, p50, p75, and p90) for 9 subsequent incidence years. 
I use the `relsurv` package and the generic quantile function.
In order to use the `rs.surv` function of the `relsurv` package, follow-up time must be defined in days in order to correspond to the population rate tables from [www.mortality.org](https://www.mortality.org/). Therefore, the estimates and corresponding 95% CI that result are also in days. I need them to be in months. Up until now, I have manually divided all estimates by 30.4166667 but this is very time-consuming and prone to mistakes.

My question is: how can I obtain results from the `rs.surv` function in months?

My R script:

```r
library(survival)
library(relsurv)

# load dataset with observed survival data
dataset <- read.spss("dataset.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels = F)

# load mortality table from mortality.org as ratetable
nlpop <- transrate.hmd("mltper_1x1_males.txt", "fltper_1x1_females.txt")

# define formula with the response as a Surv object
formula_total <- Surv(dataset$Vitfup, dataset$Vitstat) ~ dataset$Incyr

# age in observed data must be specified in days
dataset$Age_days <- dataset$Age * 365.241

# estimate the net survival with the pohar-perme method
fit_pp <- rs.surv(formula_total, rmap=list(age=Age_days, year=Incyr, sex=Gender),
                  ratetable=nlpop,data=dataset)

# calculate relative survival percentiles
quantile(fit_pp, c(0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90))

> quantile(fit_pp,c(0.10,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.90))
$`quantile`
            10  25  50   75   90
curl$Incjr=2008 29  95 354  798 2355
curl$Incjr=2009 32 104 353  837 2085
curl$Incjr=2010 30 101 371  886 2281
curl$Incjr=2011 33 118 389  914   NA
curl$Incjr=2012 35 111 364  884   NA
curl$Incjr=2013 33 120 403  943   NA
curl$Incjr=2014 39 155 440  965   NA
curl$Incjr=2015 38 137 442 1026   NA
curl$Incjr=2016 37 123 402  979   NA

$lower
            10  25  50  75   90
curl$Incjr=2008 25  85 330 769 1740
curl$Incjr=2009 29  92 334 781 1758
curl$Incjr=2010 27  91 342 834 1998
curl$Incjr=2011 30 103 368 858 2579
curl$Incjr=2012 30  99 343 840 2051
curl$Incjr=2013 29 110 382 868   NA
curl$Incjr=2014 35 137 420 921   NA
curl$Incjr=2015 35 124 407 967   NA
curl$Incjr=2016 32 110 382 909   NA

$upper
            10  25  50   75   90
curl$Incjr=2008 32 108 380  856   NA
curl$Incjr=2009 35 116 379  900 2432
curl$Incjr=2010 35 112 397  929 2977
curl$Incjr=2011 38 132 423  988   NA
curl$Incjr=2012 39 123 391  942   NA
curl$Incjr=2013 37 135 427  996   NA
curl$Incjr=2014 44 170 463 1037   NA
curl$Incjr=2015 42 154 476 1083   NA
curl$Incjr=2016 42 136 435 1094   NA

# results are in days, how to change this to months?
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Could you paste the output of `quantile(fit_pp, c(0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90))`?

Comment: I added the output to my question. Thanks for reviewing my question.